# Why am I having empty results when consulting users collection with UUID doc in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I realized that for some reason when I query for every doc in my users collection, the result is empty dispite there are docs. I realized that if the doc is a non UUID doc it works properly but I think it should also work with UUID docs.

See this image as an example:
[image]

When I perform a query the result is:
[image]

But with an automatic doc ID it works:
[image]

Do you know what could be hapening, is this intentional or am I missing any configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Documents whose IDs appear as italics in the console don't exist.  They are just there to allow you to navigate into the nested subcollections under that ID.

Comment: Oh I get it, but how can I iterate over every ID (even if tecnically it doesn't exist) to update the field of one of the under subcollections in every ID?

Comment: Read the answer again of the second marked duplicate.